# Create another sheet if only 1 exists and use it VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I had a working program that uses Sheet1 and Sheet2 in the code. However, now I realized that if I remove Sheet2 and create new sheet that sheet number is no longer being used. What I actually need to do is to create another sheet if only 1 exists and then use that in my code. However, my trials have not worked so far. I used to have code like this to define variables:

```
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim reportsheet As Worksheet

Set datasheet = Sheet1
set reportsheet = Sheet2
```

Of course this doesnt work anymore since I deleted Sheet2 and excel remembers your past mistakes. I tried to circumvent this by doing following:

```
Set datasheet = Sheet1
'Create reportsheet if it doesnt exist
Dim ws As Worksheet
CreateSheetIf = False
Set ws = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("reportdata")
On Error GoTo 0
If ws Is Nothing Then
CreateSheetIf = True
Worksheets.Add.Name = "reportdata"
End If
Set reportsheet = ws
```

Unfortunately, here I run into an error in my later code which tries to empty the reportsheet:

```
reportsheet.Range("A1:H200").ClearContents
```

What I would like to have is to create a new sheet in addition to sheet1 if there is none. This sheet should be located after the Sheet1 in the sheet listing. My further code would utilize this as the reportsheet (I move data from Sheet1 to Sheet2). Someone has any tips on what I am doing wrong and how to do it better?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to rename the sheet, or have it called Sheet1 and Sheet2. You could access it dynamically relative to their index. For example:

```
Set datasheet = Worksheets(1)    ' The first sheet in the workbook
set reportsheet = Worksheets(2)  ' The second sheet in the workbook
```

Answer (score 1):

I see lack of focus there, you first try to refer to worksheets by Object name (Sheet1, Sheet2) and then by Tab name ("reportdata").

`Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("reportdata")` with error supression is a good way to handle it, although you try to do the following after:

```
Set reportsheet = ws
```

The problem is that if you go through code, you will notice that at this stage Object `ws` is `Nothing` if there was no "reportdata" worksheet prior to running this code.

Use:

```
Set reportsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("reportdata")
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can see how I was confused about my problem. This solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the worksheet index number instead of the codename.

```
Option Explicit

Sub repBuild()
    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportsheet As Worksheet

    Set datasheet = Sheet1
    On Error GoTo createSecondWs
    Set reportsheet = Worksheets(2)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'build report here with reportsheet

    Exit Sub
createSecondWs:
    With Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        .Name = "Report Sheet"
        'perform other basic report template operations here before returning
    End With
    Resume
End Sub
```

This uses error control to create a second worksheet if only one exists.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will for sure use it in the future. However, the answer that just fixed the one faulty line I had was more practical in this case.